# Handling Special Characters like "\000", "\n", "\r", "bellchars" ; in the pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have the following python dataframe:

```
d = [{'name': ' Alice', 'age': "1 ''  2"}, {'name': '  "   ', 'age': "â"}, {'name': '', 'age': "ây"}, {'name': '', 'age': "null"}]
```

[image: Output of the above dataframe]

**I have resolved the space issues, but I also want to remove  any special character like "\000", "\n", "\r", "bellchars" coming in the dataframe.**

I tried the following code to handle special chars:

```
for col_i in df_test.columns:
        df_ascii = df_test.withColumn(col_i, unidecode(unicode(col_i, encoding = "utf-8")))
```

But it gives the the following:
[image]

I also used the following code :

```
def nonasciitoascii(unicodestring):
    return unicodestring.encode("ascii","ignore")

convertedudf = udf(nonasciitoascii)

for cols in df_test.columns:
   print(cols)
   converted = df_test.withColumn(cols,convertedudf(df_test[cols]))
```

But the Output is :

[image]

Is there a way so that I can resolve this ? I had tried some other code samples but was not able to handle the above mentioned characters(By handling I mean to remove).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `pyspark.sql.function.regexp_replace` for the same.

```py
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [{'name': ' Alice', 'age': "1 ''  2"}, 
     {'name': '  "   ', 'age': "â"}, 
     {'name': '', 'age': "ây"}, 
     {'name': '', 'age': "null"}])

df.select([
    F.regexp_replace(col, '[(\n)(\r)(\000)( )]', "").alias(col) 
    for col in df.columns]).collect()
```

Output:

```
[Row(age="1''2", name='Alice'),
 Row(age='â', name='"'),
 Row(age='ây', name=''),
 Row(age='null', name='')]
```

#### How to remove all non alphanumeric characters?

```py
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [{'name': ' Ali.|ce', 'age': "1 ''  2"}, 
     {'name': '  "   ', 'age': "â"}, 
     {'name': '', 'age': "ây"}, 
     {'name': '', 'age': "null"}])

# This expression will keep all the alphanumeric values 
# plus whatever special symbol we would like to keep 
# ex '.' and '|' are kept in this example.
df.select([
    F.regexp_replace(col, '[^(\w)+(.|)]', "").alias(col) 
    for col in df.columns]).collect()
```

Output:

```
[Row(age='12', name='Ali.|ce'),
 Row(age='', name=''),
 Row(age='y', name=''),
 Row(age='null', name='')]
```

Comment: 1) What if I have to remove any character other than alphabets and numbers ?           2) In the above code I also want to remove â, so how can I generalize that part to remove all such characters ?

Comment: Added an update to keep the words with whatever variables would would like. Please accept the answer as answered if that fits your requirement. Cheers.